# TensorFlow layer subclass input shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to make a custom layer from TensorFlow's `layers.Layer` instance.

I am trying to make a IIR filter, so that's using values from the input layer and computing an output sequence, something like this:

```
y[i] = a0 * x[i] + a1 * x[i - 1] + b1 * y[i - 1]
```

where `x` is the input and `y` is the output. I define the class this way:

```
class IIR(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, input_dim):
        super(IIR, self).__init__()
        self.input_dim = 60
        self.b0 = tf.Variable(tf.constant([uniform(-1, 1)]))
        self.b1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant([uniform(-1, 1)]))
        self.b2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant([uniform(-1, 1)]))
        self.a1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant([uniform(-1, 1)]))
        self.a2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant([uniform(-1, 1)]))
        
    def call(self, inputs):
      order = 3
      init_dim = [0,1,2]
      output_sequence = tf.constant(np.zeros((self.input_dim)),dtype=tf.float32)
      outt = np.zeros(self.input_dim)
      outt[0] = inputs[0]
      outt[1] = inputs[1]
      outt[2] = inputs[2]
      for i in range(2,self.input_dim):
        outt[i] = self.b0*inputs[i] + self.b1*inputs[i-1] + self.b2*inputs[i-2] - self.a1*outt[i-1] - self.a2*outt[i-2]
      output_sequence = tf.constant(outt)
      return output_sequence
```

but I keep getting the error

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "iir_13" (type IIR).

in user code:

    File "<ipython-input-37-0717fc982e73>", line 17, in call  *
        outt[0] = inputs[:][0]

    ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.


Call arguments received:
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 60), dtype=float32)
```

and so on. The shape of the input is `(None, 60)` (I'm setting 60 just for testing purposes) and I am assuming `None` will be replaced by batch size when training? How can I have access to the values of the input? What's the actual shape of the input? Is this the right approach?

EDIT: I am trying to implement this in a model, something like this:

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Input(shape=60))
model.add(IIR(input_dim=60))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do in these lines: `outt[0] = inputs[0]
      outt[1] = inputs[1]
      outt[2] = inputs[2]`

Comment: @AloneTogether I am trying to set the first 3 elements of the output array equal to the input to do the process from the third index forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you want to do, but I would recommend using `Tensorflow` operations only. Here is an example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

class IIR(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, input_dim):
        super(IIR, self).__init__()
        self.input_dim = input_dim
        self.b0 = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform((1,), minval=-1, maxval=1))
        self.b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform((1,), minval=-1, maxval=1))
        self.b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform((1,), minval=-1, maxval=1))
        self.a1 = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform((1,), minval=-1, maxval=1))
        self.a2 = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform((1,), minval=-1, maxval=1))
        

    def call(self, inputs):
      batch_size = tf.shape(inputs)[0]
      output_sequence = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=0, dynamic_size=True, clear_after_read=False) 
      output_sequence = output_sequence.write(0, inputs[:, 0])
      output_sequence = output_sequence.write(1, inputs[:, 1])
      output_sequence = output_sequence.write(2, inputs[:, 2])

      for i in range(2, self.input_dim):
        output_sequence = output_sequence.write(i, self.b0*inputs[:, i] + self.b1*inputs[:, i-1] 
                                                 + self.b2*inputs[:, i-2] - self.a1*output_sequence.read(i-1)
                                                 - self.a2*output_sequence.read(i-2))
      result = output_sequence.stack()
      return tf.reshape(result, tf.shape(inputs))

iir = IIR(input_dim=60)
tf.print(iir(tf.random.normal((2, 60))).shape)

iir = IIR(input_dim=60)
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=60))
model.add(IIR(input_dim=60))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
print(model.summary())
```

```
TensorShape([2, 60])
Model: "sequential_21"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 iir_80 (IIR)                (None, 60)                5         
                                                                 
 dense_20 (Dense)            (None, 8)                 488       
                                                                 
 dense_21 (Dense)            (None, 1)                 9         
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 502
Trainable params: 502
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

Comment: Thanks, Same error arises when I use this, as a layer in a model: `ValueError: Tried to convert 'shape' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported., please see the edit in the post.

Comment: what output shape do you expect?

Comment: Same as the input, in this case, a 60-data point long vector (not sure how batch_size comes into play when you want to train them)

Comment: just to add, I wanted the weights (b0, b1, b2, a1, a2) to be trainable, so just changed them to tf.Variable but this works.

Comment: Yeah, true, sorry forgot that aspect. Updated answer.